# Needed a little twitch in my scrapy code to shake off redundant data

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I wrote a code in scrapy to scrape coffee shops from yellowpage. The total data is around 870 but I'm getting around 1200 with a minimum number of duplicates. Moreover, in the csv output the data are getting placed in every alternate row. Expecting someone to provide me with a workaround. Thanks in advance.

Folder Name "yellpg"   and   "items.py" contains

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class YellpgItem(Item):
    name= Field()
    address = Field()
    phone= Field()
```

Spider Name "yellsp.py" which contains:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from yellpg.items import YellpgItem

class YellspSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "yellsp"
    allowed_domains = ["yellowpages.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=1',
    )
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('\&page=.*',)),callback='parse_item',follow=True),)
    def parse_item(self, response):
        page=response.xpath('//div[@class="info"]')
        for titles in page:
            item = YellpgItem()
            item["name"] = titles.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
            item["address"] = titles.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="streetAddress" and @class="street-address"]/text()').extract()
            item["phone"] = titles.xpath('.//div[@itemprop="telephone" and @class="phones phone primary"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

To get the CSV output, the command line I'm using:

```
scrapy crawl yellsp -o items.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend creating a pipeline that stores items to later check if the new ones are duplicates, but that isn't a real solution here, as it could create memory problems.

The real solution here is that you should avoid "storing" duplicates in your final database.

Define what field of your item is going to behave as the index in your database and everything should be working.

Comment: Hi eLRuLL, thanks for your time to answer. Duplicates are not a big deal here. The amount of it is very minimum. Perhaps the site uses ads for different cooffee shops which got parsed as well that is why the data is more in amount than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use `CSVItemExporter` in your pipeline. Create a file named `pipeline.py` inside your scrapy project and add below code lines.

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter

class CSVExportPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

     @classmethod
     def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
         pipeline = cls()
         crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
         crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
         return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open('%s_coffer_shops.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b') # hard coded filename, not a good idea
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

Now add these lines in `setting.py`

```
  ITEM_PIPELINES = {
     'your_project_name.pipelines.CSVExportPipeline': 300
  }
```

This custom `CSVItemExporter` will export your data in CSV styles. If you are not getting the data as expected you can modify `process_item` method to suits your need.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for the answer. I ran the code implementing what you have suggested here but no change at all compare to the result I received earlier. Anyways, thanks again. Btw, ain't there any shortcut way to get data in csv file without having alternate row blank.

Comment: In Python 2, open outfile with mode 'wb' instead of 'w'. The csv.writer writes `\r\n` into the file directly. If you don't open the file in binary mode, it will write `\r\r\n` because on Windows text mode will translate each `\n` into `\r\n`. Try tweaking this line `file = open('%s_coffer_shops.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')` to `file = open('%s_coffer_shops.csv' % spider.name, 'wb')`

Comment: I'm using python 3 here.

Comment: Then it's very easy. `open('%s_coffer_shops.csv' % spider.name, 'w', newline='')`. Python 3 open has `newline` paratmeter set it to `''` empty string.